# Trying to display information coming from the database in a list and a div with only one select

Tags: php

Im reading questions and answers columns of  my faq table.

And I want to show my faq questions and correspondent answers where status is icual to 1.

I know how can I do this with two selects, but with one select Im not see how it is possible.

Because I can´t do something like my **example1**: (Because Im repeating my `<ol> </ol>` in my while loop and dont works great.)

Do you know how can I do this using just one select?

**example1:**

```
<div id="container">
<?php
    $read = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE status = 1");
    $lines = mysql_num_rows($pesquisa);
?>
    <h2>FAQ: Answers to  <?php echo $lines ?>  frequently asked questions.</h2>
    <?php
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
        $question = $result['question'];
        $answer = $result['answer'];
        echo '<ol>';
            echo '<li><a href="">'.$question.'</a></li>';
        echo '</ol>';
        echo '<hr/>';
        echo '<div id="answers">';
            echo '<h2>'.$question.'</h2>';
            echo '<p>'.$answer.'</p>';
        echo '</div>';  
    }
     ?>
   </div>
```

**My code:**

```
<div id="container">
    <?php
  $read = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE status = 1");
  $lines = mysql_num_rows($pesquisa);
  ?>
    <h2>FAQ: Answers to  <?php echo $lines ?>  frequently asked questions.</h2>
    <ol>
        <?php
          while($result = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
            $question = $result['question'];
            $answer = $result['answer'];
            echo '<li><a href="">'.$question.'</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
    </ol>    
    <hr/>
    <div id="answers">
        <h2><?php echo $question; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $answer; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright, here is what you looking for;

```
    <div id="container">
    <?php
  $read = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE status = 1");
  $lines = mysql_num_rows($pesquisa);
  $results = array();
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
  $results[]=$result;
    }
  ?>
    <h2>FAQ: Answers to  <?php echo $lines ?>  frequently asked questions.</h2>
<ol>
        <?php
            foreach($results as $result){
            $question = $result['question'];
            $answer = $result['answer'];
            $link='#'.$question;
            echo '<li><a href='.$link.'>'.$question.'</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
    </ol>    
    <hr/>
    <div id="answers">
    <?php
        foreach($results as $result){
        $question = $result['question'];
        $answer = $result['answer'];
        echo'<div id='.$question.'>';
        echo"<h2>".$question."</h2>";
        echo"<p>".$answer."</p>";
        } 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im having some warnings using your example. Warning: Illegal string offset 'question' and 'answer'!

Comment: Forget, I forgot brackets here $results[]=$result; It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking but is it something like this?

```
<div id="container">
    <?php
  $read = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE status = 1");
  $lines = mysql_num_rows($pesquisa);
  ?>
    <h2>FAQ: Answers to  <?php echo $lines ?>  frequently asked questions.</h2>
    <ol>
        <?php
          while($result = mysql_fetch_array($read)){
            $question = $result['question'];
            $answer = $result['answer'];
            echo '<li><a href="#'.str_replace(" ","",$question).'">'.$question.'</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
    </ol>    
    <hr/>
    <div id="answers">
        <?php
          reset($read);
          while($result = mysql_fetch_array($read)){ ?>
               <h2 name='<?php echo str_replace(" ","",$question); ?>'><?php echo $result['question']; ?></h2>
               <p><?php echo $result['answer']; ?></p>
          <? }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are just dealing with a formatting issue then don't use the ol tag...you can reproduce any effect you want with simple divs.

Comment: It is a list of questions so a list is semanticly the right thing to use

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array :

```
<div id="container">
    <?php
  $read = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM faq WHERE status = 1");
  $lines = mysqli_num_rows($pesquisa);
  $result = mysqli_fetch_all($read); //<- Put all results in one array to work on
  ?>
    <h2>FAQ: Answers to  <?php echo $lines ?>  frequently asked questions.</h2>
    <ol>
        <?php
        foreach($row in $result) {
            echo '<li><a href="">'.$row['question'].'</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
    </ol>    
    <hr/>
    <div id="answers">
    <?php
    foreach($row in $result) {
        echo '<h2>'. $row['question'].'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'. $row['answer'].'</p>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, beat me to it. But need mysqli_* everywhere and not mix with mysql_* and change the connect to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It also works, but I really need to change the conection to use your code. But mysqli seems to be more safe than my sql. So maybe its better to think about change to mysqli. But, do you know if this line of your code "$result = mysqli_fetch_all($read); " exists with "normal" mysql? Or with normal mysql we need always to use a while loop to put all results in one array?

Comment: As far as i know, with mysql_* you need to loop to populate your array (as shown in Athul's answer)